# What is the correct syntax and parameters for fileServiceData for XPages to IBMSBT?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, ibm-sbt

I am testing the SBT and when I set a data source via the fileservicedata binding e.g.

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xe:fileServiceData var="fileServiceData1" endpoint="connections" timeout="0" clearOnRendering="true">
        <xe:this.serviceType>
            <xe:connectionsFileData loaded="true"></xe:connectionsFileData>
        </xe:this.serviceType>
    </xe:fileServiceData>
</xp:this.data>
```

It does not work. However if I choose the JavaScript approach e.g.

```
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://
var fileService = new com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.files.FileService();
return fileService.getMyFiles(null);
}]]></xp:this.value>
```

I get data returned. What can be the cause of failure for the first approach? It is the default approach in the xpagessbt demo db.

Comment: I assume the double "<" at your opening <xp:this.data> is just a typo? - Apart from that: do you see an error, or what else is returned if anything?

Comment: you might also look at your IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT/ folder to check what the xpages log says

Comment: this is what I see in the log: `com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Error while calling the file service: null. Failed to access URL: null`

Comment: what does you managed-bean configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

What SBT version are you using? What Domino version? What do the logs say? Could you pls share the faces config and the xsp properties file?

Not easy but in order to find out the issue you could run the SDK from Eclipse to debug this particular code. If you want to do this let me know and I send instructions.